# Why am I getting this error: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, types

I am trying to write a value to a cell using google app scripts. This is the code I am using to do so at row 800 column 1.

```
function assignKey(keyNumber) {
  try{
    var assignedKeysSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL)
    var keyCell = assignedKeysSheet.getRange(800, 1)
    keyCell.setValue(keyNumber)
  }catch(e){
    return e.message
  }

    return keyNumber
}
```

However when I run this I get the error:

```
The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
```

I have looked at the documentation for this function [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) and it specifies that `getRange` takes four parameters of type Number. I thought that was what I was passing it so I am not sure why it thinks the first parameter is a String when it is clearly a Number. I have even tried casting 800 to a NUmber using `Number(800)` which seemed silly but still did not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Cooper That results in a similar error

Comment: Actually I finally realized that assignedKeysSheet is a spreadsheet and your range doesn't include a sheet name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
function question101() {
  var assignedKeysSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url")
  var keyCell = assignedKeysSheet.getRange('Sheet1!A800')
  keyCell.setValue(12)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I made those changes, however, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I kept getting the same error,

```
The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
```

using this code:

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
range = activeSheet.getRange(800, 1)
```

Then I added the missing layer:

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = activeSheet.getSheets()[0];
range = sheet.getRange(800, 1)
```

And it worked. I'm guessing your code would work with:

```
var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
var assignedKeysSheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
range = assignedKeysSheet.getRange(800, 1)
```